# WordPress. ACF PRO кнопка добавления блока

Tags: wordpress, acf

Создал страницу в WordPress с помощью ACF PRO, на которой будет выводится контент в виде двух столбцов с текстом или изображением (смотря, что выберет пользователь).

Вопрос: как добавить кнопку "Добавить блок", по нажатию на нее должен добавляться аналогичный блок на этой же странице с такими же двумя столбцами, в который можно добавить или текст или изображение. И можно ли это сделать через ACF PRO.

P.S. Пробовал через repeater, но возникли сложности с выводом контента, может, есть другой способ?

Comment: Осваивайте repeater, он для того и придуман.

Answer (score 0):

Это достаточно просто с помощью foreach. Если брать ваш случай то создаете повторитель внутри него создаете группу с нужными вам элементами. Повторитель это массив и вам достаточно прогнать все через цикл чтобы вывести все элементы.
Пример вывода:

```
$repeater = get_field('repeater');

foreach($repeater as $item_group) {
 $item = $item_group['group'];
 echo "
        <img src="' . $item['image'] . '" />
        <div>' . $item['text1'] . '</div>
        <div>' . $item['text2'] . '</div>
      ";
}
```